# Are the new weapons available as random drops?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It's been awhile since the last weapons-including update, and I cannot recall if new weapons are immediately added to the randomly dropped weapons the game gives out during play.

Are the 5 new weapons from the 'love-themed' TF2 update all available as randomly dropped weapons?

Similar and unrelated - Are non-strange versions of the Bread weapons also available for random drops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, yes they are. Source: Pic below.

[image]

A note, bread skins do not drop.  Rather, they are uncrated from [Bread Boxes](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bread_Box), which are crafted by crafting 3 craft hats together.

Answer (score 3):

Well, [a Tide Turner dropped for me](http://tf2b.com/tf2/item/76561198013182579/2688413119), and I recall other weapons dropping for other people, so there's no reason to assume the other new weapons don't drop.

I'm seeing claims on the wiki that the bread reskins do not drop, though I'd sit on that for a bit until it becomes fully operational again before trusting it.

Comment: Well, that pretty much proves that at least one of them drops.  I'll hold off on accepting for now, in case any clear evidence about the bread pops up in the next few days.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the bread boxes are only available for craft until July, I would say that the reskinned items will not drop now, doubtful ever. I've gotten drops of the new weapons but have only unboxed the reskins, which are most commonly unique quality and sometimes strange. Ideally, the reskins will become worth more than a few hats in the future but we can only speculate. I would not expect to be able to get more bread boxes for more reskin opportunities after [July 9th.](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bread_box)